# Response from model is undefined when using async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to return data to my view template. I'm using async.waterfall for doing this. There is just one problem, the result from the class is always `undefined`

controller:

```
Profile().then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

model:

```
module.exports = async function Profile() {
    let waterfall = await Async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            db.getOneWhere('users', 'username', global.req.params.username, ["username"]).then(result => {
                callback(null, result);
            });
        },
        function(arg1, callback) {
            db.getOneWhere('users', 'username', 'admin', ["username"]).then(result2 => {
                let ok = {
                    arg1,
                    result2
                }
                callback(null, ok);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        let tmp = [];
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function(k) {
            tmp = [...tmp, ...result[k]];
        });

        return {'data': tmp};
    });

    return waterfall;
}
```

`let waterfall` is always `undefined` so the response from `Profile.then()...` is also undefined. Why is it not working and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you mean this [async.waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall)? If so then this function returns `undefined` because it is defined that way. `await` does not magically convert a callback based function to one that returns a promise.

Comment: @t.niese okay, thanks for the explanation. do you have any suggestions on how i can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would wrap the `Async.waterfall` into a `Promise` the callback of the waterfall would then only do the reject/resolve the promise. The created Promise will then resolve with the result of the waterfall or be rejected if an error occured.

```
module.exports = async function Profile() {
  let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Async.waterfall([ /*....*/ ], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(result)
      }
    })
  })

  let tmp = [];
  Object.keys(result).forEach(function(k) {
    tmp = [...tmp, ...result[k]];
  });

  return {
    'data': tmp
  };
}
```